# CSS Disappearing on Mobile Device

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Using the Bootstrap front-end framework and after a certain section of the website, the CSS will not appear on mobile devices but will when viewing it from a browser. I'm unsure if this section is somehow in an interference with another section of the site. The code and CSS for the div in question is below:

HTML:

```
<div class="project-right">
    <div class="container">
        <div class"row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                ....
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.project-right {
    background-color: black;
    padding: 110px 0px;
}
```

I've included `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in my  section of the website.

Website can be found at: http://bit.ly/1CEdcBj.

Comment: so the padding and background are not functional on mobile? is this the issue? The css seems global, it ain't within any media query so there is no reason it shall not appear..

Comment: @KAD exactly my thoughts... But not the case here. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `media` property in your header link to value :

`'only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'` ...

The shall force the css to get applied on both screen and max-device-width (i.e your mobile device) :

```
    <link rel='stylesheet' media='only screen and (max-device-width: 480px)'
        href='/your/css/file.css' />
```

I haven't tried it though...

Comment: Does this apply even though there is a single style sheet?

Comment: This is not related how many style sheets you really have, it does apply for the style sheet you are linking and setting the media property for.. If you have more than one stylesheet that you are linking you can set the media property for each one.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure which section you are talking about but there are some media queries in your CSS code, which show elements on just big screens such as this:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px)
```

Comment: Isn't that to declare that, if the screen size is at least 600px wide, display *code*?

Comment: Also, the section in question is anything below the blue parallax section. I've created a div in there that is supposed declare: background-color: black; however it doesn't show on mobile devices. That is the issue at hand.

Comment: media queries is not for hiding or showing code, it is to write some css code which apply based on the screen size for example more about it there: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: I am fully aware of what Media Queries are and what the do. That doesn't negate the fact that the div styles aren't showing up on mobile devices.

Comment: Is this just happening on mobile devices or also when you resize the browser? will be helpful if you show me a screen shot of the problem.

Comment: This is only happening on mobile devices. 

Desktop: http://postimg.org/image/x0ks92ivf/
Desktop (resize): http://postimg.org/image/q7ftz22ob/
Mobile (iPhone 6): http://postimg.org/image/q8ud67tvv/

Comment: try to give this div:   display: block;